# Epplus: When using LoadFromCollection, boolean column is blank in exported Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

In my MVC application, I have an ActionResult that loads an IEnumerable and exports it to an Excel File. That part works great, unless I have a boolean column. In that case, the values of the boolean column are blank.

Are boolean columns not supported by LoadFromCollection?

To resolve this, I could create a separate field in the model that translates the boolean value to a string value. However, I was hoping I could add a statement in the `ExcelPackage()` block that does the job without needing to adjust the model. Is this possible, or is rewriting the model the only possible solution?

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(string _searchString, string _setScale)
{                
   // This is the query result set the user wishes to export to file
   IEnumerable<CreditsAllsExport> exportQuery;
   /* ... irrelevant code redacted ... */
   exportQuery = exportQuery.AsEnumerable();

   byte[] response;
   using (var excelFile = new ExcelPackage())
   {
      /* ... irrelevant code redacted ... */
      worksheet.Cells["A5"].LoadFromCollection(Collection: exportQuery, PrintHeaders: true);

      /* TRANSLATE BOOLEAN TO Yes or No */

      response = excelFile.GetAsByteArray();
  }

  /* ... irrelevant code redacted ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly fine...

```
        var rnd = new Random();

        var pkg = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");

        var blist = new List<bool>();
        for(int i=0; i < 20;i++) {
            blist.Add(rnd.NextDouble() > .5 ? true : false);
        }

        ws.Cells["A5"].LoadFromCollection(blist, true);

        pkg.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"c:\tmp\bool.xlsx"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my data set, the boolean values do not appear in the exported Excel column. On both the View index page and the underlying SQL Server table, the boolean values exist. Why they do not appear in any form in the Excel document is a mystery.

Comment: This is embarrassing. The field didn't appear because I failed to add it in the column definition at the beginning of the ActionResult block.

Comment: Well, `LoadFromCollection` definitely works for boolean values, so the problem is elsewhere. It also works with complex classes that have boolean properties (I've just tried). In your code, you are using the class `CreditsAllsExport`. What does this class look like? -- Just saw your comment. Glad you could resolve your problem :-)

Comment: You are correct. As in the previous comment, I failed to include a column in my linq query definition.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing, but it turns out that my column didn't appear in the results because I had failed to include it in my select statement.

As @Izydrmr showed, boolean values **are** supported by LoadFromCollection. So the the take-home point is that if a boolean column doesn't appear, then check the select statement.

```
IEnumerable<CreditsAllsExport> exportQuery =
   from s in db.CreditsAlls
   select new CreditsAllsExport
   {
      FiscalYear = s.FiscalYear,
      Campus = s.Campus,
      StudentName = s.StudentName,
      CourseID = s.CourseID,
      CourseTitle = s.CourseTitle,
      CreditEarned = s.CreditEarned,
      DateEarned = s.DateEarned,
      Department = s.Department,
      School = s.School,
      Teacher = s.Teacher,
      /* I had forgotten this column*/ Transfer=s.Transfer,  
      CampusSchoolMatch = s.CampusSchoolMatch
  };
```

Comment: Another take-home point may be that redacted, presumably 'irrelevant' code may be relevant after all ;-)

Comment: It's a balancing act. When I don't redact code, the complaint is that I'm pasting too much code; when I do redact code, something is missing.